# Getting text from webpart properties in kentico

Tags: kentico

Working with kentico 10. I have implemented a custom webpart following the steps from https://docs.kentico.com/k10/custom-development/developing-web-parts/creating-new-web-parts.

I have created a webpart property which gets the data from a SQL query like below

```
SELECT
  DocumentGuid AS value, 
  DocumentName AS text 
FROM
  View_CMS_Tree_Joined 
WHERE 
  NodeAliasPath LIKE '/SomePath' 
  AND DocumentCulture LIKE 'en-us' 
ORDER BY
  DocumentName
```

In the .cs file, I am reading the value selected on this form using the below code as specified in the kentico documentation.

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get
    {
        return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty ( GetValue ( "MyProperty" ).ToString ( ), "" );
    }
}
```

This property gives me the **DocumentGuid** ('*value*') from the SQL query above which is working as expected. Is there a method to read the **DocumentName** ('*text*') from the SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can get documentname  from current context like this

```
CMS.DocumentEngine.DocumentContext.CurrentDocument.DocumentName
```

Comment: That will not work as webpart form will have a different set of results from the SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in code you'd do something like:

`string docName = ""; 
var doc = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments("custom.pagetype").WhereEquals("DocumentGuid", MyProperty).FirstObject;
if (doc != null)
{
    docName = doc.DocumentName;
}`

If you needed a macro you'd do something like this:

`Documents["/Your-path"].Children.WithAllData.Where("DocumentGUID = 'your guid'").FirstItem.DocumentName`

Comment: My SQL query return 20+ results and I have to loop through all of them and make 20+ DB calls. It would be ideal for me to just read the "text" from the webpart property.

Comment: Then use javascript because the template will only store the web part's value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to get "Text" from drop down something like `dropdownList.SelectedItem.Text;` 
It is not possible. All web parts are inherited from [CMSAbstractWebPart](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/10_0/api/html/T_CMS_PortalEngine_Web_UI_CMSAbstractWebPart.htm)
The only thing you can get is [property value](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/10_0/api/html/M_CMS_PortalEngine_Web_UI_CMSAbstractWebPart_GetValue.htm). The only way can get is to create you own method in web part to query DB.

```
DataSet _myDocs = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments()
.Path("/SomePath", PathTypeEnum.Children).Culture("en-us").Result;
```